# cronjob won't save after reboot

Tags: bash, scripts, cron

I've created a simple script that pings a server, and reboots my machine if the server doesn't respond.  if it does respond, it just exits the script.

I've added the script to cron via crontab -e, specifically as follows

*/8 * * * * /root/hive/bin/pingtest

once I add it, I can see cron executing the "pingtest" every 8 minutes just as I commanded.  however, once the machine reboots (for whatever reason), that specific line in crontab is gone, it doesn't presist through reboots.

I've tried editing via root, I've tried editing via sudo, but nothing persists.

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried adding here /var/spool/cron/root and reloading the service?

Comment: Do any other files vanish after a reboot? Are there other files that you create that persist?

Comment: nothing else vanishes that I know of.  The other cron jobs persist as far as I know.  my files persist, as do changes to said files.  I'm trying to add this to an already packaged ubuntu, and the makers say there is "no support for that" so I can't get any help from them.  I'm fairly new to using cron and adding to it, so I have no doubt that is part of my issue.

Comment: It might help future readers if you included information about what the "already packaged ubuntu" is in your question

Answer (score 0):

ok I found the culprit. it was in etc/crontab.root. that file populates my cron job list every boot, I just added my changes to it, and viola.